# Why does casting to dynamic list fails when indexing?

Tags: c#, serialization, casting

After getting exception
`Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type anonymous` when trying to get item values using indexer like:

(Simplified code snippets)

```
List<Foo> foos = GetFoos();
List<dynamic> dynamicFoos = foos.Cast<dynamic>().ToList();
foreach (var foo in dynamicFoos)
{
  var Value = foo["Name"]; // fail
}
```

I found myself writing this: (C#)

```
List<dynamic> dynamicFoos = foos.Select(f=> ConvertToDynamic(f)).ToList();
foreach (var foo in dynamicFoos)
{
  var Value = foo["Name"]; // Succeeded
}
```

Using the method:

```
private dynamic ConvertToDynamic(Foo foo){
  string Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Foo);
  dynamic dynamicFoo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Json);
  return dynamicFoo;
}
```

This works but I'm sure there's a better practice than deserializing serialized objects.

.Net Fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/aTZbZm (Based on the link from @Fildor comment)

Can someone explain why the casting behavior is different from the serializing?
Or maybe give a better solution?

Comment: Try `var Value = foo.Name;` instead: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dOJqFw

Comment: May be related to the actual runtime type behind "dynamic"? Really not sure.

Comment: What is `GetFoos()` returning? .Net classes? If that's the case, a class object, without your *intervention* (creating an indexer on `this` that returns property values by property name through reflection), doesn't index properties like this. Your `ConvertToDynamic()` returns a JObject which instead indexes the names of properties.

Comment: @Fildor I cant use `.name` because I'm getting the fields names dynamically

Comment: @Jimi `GetFoos()` returning a list of simple .Net classes that does not contain any indexer in it.

Comment: So you can't use an indexer to get the value/content of a Property by name.

Comment: @Jimi Take a look at the .Net Fiddle example that I've added in my last edit

Comment: As mentioned, your *serializer* creates JObjects and a JObject has an indexer on property names. Your ,Net class doesn't. `dynamic` is not *magic*, is just late binding.

Comment: ^^ That being said, If you do not want to serialize, you maybe want to use reflection: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FqXYY9 (which I very rarely recommend).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying doesn't work because the dynamic representation of your object doesn't have an indexer (since your original object doesn't have an indexer). You have two options here:

- If this is something relatively rare, reflection is much faster and easier to use. Simply get the property by name and get its value as normal. Aggressive caching will allow you to use it more before feeling its performance hit.
- If this is something that will be running a very large amount of time, the cost of implementing dynamic compiler call sites gets amortized against it all and it starts being worth it. The first run will be rough though. As to the actual implementation, you want to build an `ExpandoObject` `dynamic`, which internally uses a `Dictionary` of property names to values. You have to manually fill in that dictionary before using it, it's not as simple as a cast.

Your serialize-deserialize approach is worse than both options above, since it does a lot more operations (string manipulation and parsing) than necessary. Conceptually though, it's more similar to #1 since it doesn't implement `ExpandoObjects`.

Comment: The serialize/deserialize also has the downside that new objects are created. If you are just reading the properties that *may* be fine, so long as you are OK missing any updates made to the original objects